# Форум на java, как реализовать создание тем(новых страниц) пользователями?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, mvc

Пишу сайт, Spring MVC

За frontend отвечает bootstrap + JSP

Вот задача, пользователь создает новую тему на форуме(например: Обсудим политику)

Соответственно, должна появиться новая view с новым адресом"/newPage1" Как это реализовать?

Comment: У тебя должен быть один шаблон для всех тем, и уже после запроса, смотреть(читать из базы), что нужно в этот шаблон поставить. Врятли хорошая идея создавать физически файл на каждую тему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создавать стандартную jsp для всех тем, аля:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>${subject.name}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
       ${subject.text}
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

И по запросу на тему заполнять ее

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/subject", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteBasketProduct(@RequestParam("subject") String subjectName, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    DataBase db = new DataBase(); //Ваше собственное реализованное хранилище, которое будет возвращать хранимую тему
    Subject sb = db.getSubject(subjectName); //Ваша модель темы
    modelAndView.addObject("subject", sb);
    return "subjectName.jsp";
}
```

Comment: А еще лучше как сказал Михаил. Хранить в БД все данные об теме и уже заполнять стандартную jsp по запросу к ней.